# 2000 mustang v6 3.8l tapping noise camshaft sychronizer bearing or timing chain?

Tags: maintenance, automatic-transmission, mustang

My car makes this tapping noise (chain like tapping noise) and  (most noticeable) when driving up hill, or at low speeds under a load. Another that has started to happen after this issue, is a type of pressure releasing sound and almost like something is slowing down right after I turn the engine off.

Here's a video on youtube of a another mustang that is having the same exact tapping noise as I am https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqJm7VNu5dc&feature=youtu.be

Ive seen alot people saying its the camshaft sychronizer bearing going bad. Any thoughts? 
Ps, I just found this, could this be why? http://www.explorerforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=278100

Pss these are some comments from the people in the video

sweat504 9 months ago
 Camshaft synchronizer ,exactly what mine did installed it boom fixed it

Tony Patterson 2 years ago
 i have the same problem , i have replaced water pump,power steering pump,oil pump,harmonic balancer,timing chain tensioner,new belt,new plugs and still knocking,does anybody have a f##king clue,ive spent 1300.00 chasing this knock,i can buy a rebuilt motor for 1500.00, anybody know what the fix is???

Comment: Have you checked for exhaust leaks between the head and exhaust manifolds?

Comment: I was actually planing on doing that eventually, but im pretty sure that's not the cause of the tapping noise? maybe the releasing pressure noise?

Comment: It's really amazing how close the sound of a leaking exhaust manifold can sound like a tapping rocker arm or even a rod knock. You'd really be surprised.

Comment: have you checked the catalytic converters?

Comment: No i have not, but i think there would be a code popping up if my cats were bad, right? And i havnt checked the exhaust manifold

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: +DucatiKiller I have not resolved it but it seems like a cylinder is struggling on the power cycle when the ambient temperature around the car changes (in the afternoon and around 80°). I can see it being a bad bearing, lifter or rod nock. Overall, it's not worth fixing.